# how to make use of google android sample code demo

Tags: android, android-studio

As I mention above,being new to android, I learn some fundament knowledge about android development,maybe just a little.Now I start it in the Google android doc, just got trouble at the beginning. I don't know how to deal with its sample code I downloaded from the website. I tried importing the sample in android studio 2.0,but I couldn't make it run properly.And the file I IMPORTED SEEMS NOT COMPLETE AS I created and ran well before, lots of them missing

Comment: Kindly post the errors or issues that you're facing?

Comment: @YasirTahir , not some specified errors, just don't know how to use the sample code,the demos google provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clean, rebuild and then run the project.

1> Click Build>Clean

2> Click Build>Rebuild project

3> Run your app.

Comment: In what project should I execute your indications

Comment: @JimJayLee Import any sample project that you want to study about and then follow my instructions

Comment: Thx ,it helps.BTW,what about the projects from the github. Is the method available for it

Comment: @JimJayLee yeah it will be same, Just unpackage the project and follow the same